# Streaming data from web-server, trying to use vb.net and cgi

Tags: streaming

I need to stream data from a web server to clients. The data is location data that is collected and stored on the server. The clients will click a button on an html page to 'opt in' to start receiving the data. This data is never ending and there is at least one of the clients that needs to receive the data 24-7, with as few breaks as possible. The data being streamed will be client specific, as each client wont receive the exact same data.

I've done several multi-threaded tcp servers over sockets, and websockets are the way I would like to attack this, but the requirements are that this has to work in ie9.

The initial requirement was that this be a vb.net cgi executable - but during testing, I havent been able to 'use' the stream from the vb.net executable until the app finishes - like it wasn't able to flush the stdout even though I was specificly using the console.out.flush(). So If this isn't a viable option, and I can support this with facts, then I can get this requirement changed.

I've also read quite a bit about using a third party server to stream the data like Orbit and APE I think was a couple of them, but requirements are for 1 server - the web server. No other hardware can be required.

I'm pretty sure the vb.net CGI isn't the ideal solution based on what i've found, but is it doable or do I need to abandon that solution and move on to a newer technology , ISAPI? Any ideas or suggestions, even if they just point me in the right direction, are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You might go few ways.

If you would go C# .Net, then you might look into Silverlight solution. But it requires plugin in browser to be installed (like Flash). Good thing here, is that you are able to send data through normal sockets, in pure realtime from server. In same time Silverlight uses .Net so it makes some code to be shared. That helps development process. As well the way it will work in different browsers will be same.

You might have a look in similar solution using Java Applet with Java backend (can be even .Net, but again, easier to develop when both in same language).

Another option is to have fron-end using WebSockets, but as you know its not supported in IE9 and below (IE10 promises to be), and Opera is not supporting it as well.
Backend can be done in what you prefer. But bear in mind that WebSockets uses framing, and for constant but little packets its not efficient, because if you send 10 bytes, then it will create frame 2-12 bytes, and TCP packet header that is 40 bytes in average.

To support older browsers you might have a look in long-polling, but it is not as reliable as websockets.

As well it is important to calculate the amount of data and approximate amount of users that will use your system. Based on calculations you will have approximate information about how real it is, and what server will be required to handle.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I am really trying to get the ok to do this with Websockets but I don't know if the ie9 requirement can be lifted. anyway - thanks.